# Generic Javascript Logic structure

Tags: javascript, toggle, nested

I do I write this in basic javascript syntax

If DIV1 is visible DIV3 should be able to toggle HIDE/SHOW DIV1
If DIV2 is visible DIV3 should be able to toggle HIDE/SHOW DIV2

I want to be able to toggle whichever toggle view is showing up. If that makes sense.

I do not know how to add the second set of toggle logic to this.

```
function toggleMenuDiv() {
var full = document.getElementById('full');
var thumb = document.getElementById('fullthumb');
var butt = document.getElementById('button');
   if (full.style.display == 'none') {
     full.style.display = 'block';
     thumb.style.display = 'none';
     butt.innerHTML = 'THUMB VIEW<span class="arrow-e"></span>';
   }
   else {
     full.style.display = 'none';
     thumb.style.display = 'block';
     butt.innerHTML = 'FULL VIEW<span class="arrow-e"></span>';
   }
}
```

Comment: How would you handle the case when neither DIV1 nor DIV2 are visible?

Comment: One is always visible

Comment: So what you actually want is if DIV1 is visible and user clicks DIV3, it will hide DIV1 and show DIV2?

Comment: I have a thumbnail view and a full view. DIV3 is a button HIDE/SHOW that I want to HIDE/SHOW whichever of the other two views is showing. If it hides and neither is showing other content on the page will be displayed so that's alright. I already created the first thing you mentioned with my code above.

Comment: I wont change this until you respond but here is a link to what I am trying to do. http://www.codecademy.com/galnova/codebits/7VD9rZ/edit I need to make that show/hide button show or hide whichever div is visible.

Comment: [This is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjA5m/1/) with your code and some random html. What do you want to happen that is not happening? I'm still a tad confused what you want.

Comment: I fixed the issue I am sorry. I do have a follow up question though. I want to move alot of the local variables to the top of the page to be more DRY. But when I do remove them from the functions the functions no longer work. Can you tell me why?